# Spring Boot Integration test error : Load balancer does not have available server for client:

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am working with Spring boot, eureka and micro services.

I have 2 micro service m1 and m2, where m1 internally calls m2.

I am executing integration tests in m1 LOCALLY.

when m1 calls m2, an exception is thrown,

> "Load balancer does not have available server for client: m2"

Can anyone help here ? what might be the problem.

Surprisingly, when I run m1 and access it directly it works.
The problem is only when I run integration test.

Comment: If m1 calls to m2, and you are testing m1, then I assume you should include / start the m2 also (maybe by adding the proper configuration files to the relevant tests)

Comment: Yes, When I test m1, i am making sure m2 is up and running.